# Jupyter Notebook not importing pandas module

Tags: python, jupyter, ipython

I am running Jupyter on a server on a virtual environment. I then tunnel my connection so I can access Jupyter on my browser.

When I SSH into the server, I can use the Panda module in both Ipython and Python3.

I ran this code in Ipython

```
 import pandas as pd                                                     

In [2]: print(pd.__file__)                                                      
/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py
```

Then I tried adding it to my path in Jupyter with the code below, still no luck.

```
import os
os.getcwd() 
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py')

import pandas as pd
```

I used these instructions to setup the Virtual Environment https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-jupyter-notebook-with-python-3-on-ubuntu-18-04

Thank you very much in advance, this will help me with my school studies a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I had to start the virtual environment, then install pandas module

```
source virtual_enviornment_folder/bin/activate
pip install pandas
```

Comment: You probably lacked dependencies to make pandas work in Jupyter (perhaps DataFrame display packages?)